# Dafny - Substring implementation

Tags: substring, verification, proof, dafny

Im trying to write a simple verified implementation of the substring method.
My method accepts 2 strings and checks whether str2 is in str1.
Im trying to figure out firstly why my invairant doesnt hold - Dafny marks that the invariant might not hold on entry and while my pre/post conditions fail.
My thoughts on the invairant are that there 3 main scenarios:
1. The loop failed to find the substring at index i and there are more indexes to explore
2. The loop failed to find the substring at index i - no more indexes to explore
3. The loop found substring at index i

Code:

```
method Main() {
    var str1,str2 := "Dafny","fn";
    var found,offset := FindSubstring(str1,str2);
    assert found by
    {
        calc {
            str2 <= str1[2..];
        ==>
            IsSubsequenceAtOffset(str1,str2,2);
        ==>
            IsSubsequence(str1,str2);
        ==
            found;
        }
    }
    assert offset == 2 by
    {
        assert found && str2 <= str1[2..];
        assert offset != 0 by { assert 'D' == str1[0] != str2[0] == 'f'; }
        assert offset != 1 by { assert 'a' == str1[1] != str2[0] == 'f'; }
        assert offset != 3 by { assert 'n' == str1[3] != str2[0] == 'f'; }
        assert !(offset >= 4) by { assert 4 + |str2| > |str1|; }
    }
    print "The sequence ";
    print str2;
    print " is a subsequence of ";
    print str1;
    print " starting at element ";
    print offset;
}

predicate IsSubsequence<T>(q1: seq<T>, q2: seq<T>)
{
    exists offset: nat :: offset + |q2| <= |q1| && IsSubsequenceAtOffset(q1,q2,offset)
}

predicate IsSubsequenceAtOffset<T>(q1: seq<T>, q2: seq<T>, offset: nat)
{ 
    offset + |q2| <= |q1| && q2 <= q1[offset..]
}

predicate Inv<T>(str1: seq<T>, str2: seq<T>, offset: nat, found: bool)
{
    |str1| > 0 && |str2| > 0 && |str1| >= |str2| && offset <= |str1|-|str2| &&
    (!found && offset < |str1|-|str2| ==> !(str2 <= str1[offset..])) &&
  (!found && offset == |str1| -|str2| ==> !IsSubsequence(str1, str2)) && 
    (found ==> IsSubsequenceAtOffset(str1, str2, offset))
}

method FindSubstring(str1: string, str2: string) returns (found: bool, offset: nat)

    requires |str2| <= |str1|
    ensures found <==> IsSubsequence(str1,str2)
    ensures found ==> IsSubsequenceAtOffset(str1,str2,offset)  
  {
     found, offset := str2 <= str1[0..], 0;
     assert Inv(str1,str2,offset,found);

     while !found && offset <= (|str1| - |str2|) 
        invariant Inv(str1,str2,offset,found)
     {
       if str2 <= str1[(offset + 1)..] {
         found, offset := true, offset + 1;
       } else {
         offset := offset + 1;
       }
     } 
     Lemma(str1,str2,found,offset);
  }

  lemma Lemma(str1: string, str2: string, found: bool, offset: nat)
    requires !(!found && offset <= (|str1| - |str2|))
    requires Inv(str1,str2,offset,found)
    ensures found <==> IsSubsequence(str1,str2)
    ensures found ==> IsSubsequenceAtOffset(str1,str2,offset) 
    {}
```

Link: http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/QaAbU
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/q9BG

1) `|str1| > 0 && |str2| > 0` in `inv` was failing because this condition is not added in the requirement of the function `FindSubstring`

2) Since while loop body in `FindSubstring` checks substring for `offset+1`, the while loop only has to run for `offset < (|str1| - |str2|)` because if `offset == (|str1| - |str2|)` then there doesn't exist any offset which would satisfy `str2 <= str1[offset..]`

3) Added quantifier in `inv` which ensures that for all the offsets `k` where `0 <= k <= offset`, there doesn't exist any `k` which `str2 <= str1[offset..]`

A small advice to debug the failing invariant that might help: replace the `inv` call with the actual body of `inv` and dafny will pinpoint the failing condition in the invariant.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer!